# ISO 8601 Duration with milliseconds?

Tags: time, duration, iso8601

How should a duration of 500 milliseconds be expressed using ISO 8601? To me, the [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is not 100% clear. Is it just "PT0.5S" ?

Comment: I can't answer, but I can agree with your interpretation. It's too bad that Wikipedia is the best "documentation" readily available, as the full spec must be purchased from ISO to give an answer.

Comment: I've often thought that making people pay for a standards document isn't promoting the standard very well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

I could only find an old draft for 8601 but it is explicit on the fractional representation:

> 5.5 Periods of time
>
> 5.5.1 Means of specifying periods of time
>
> A period of time shall be expressed in one of the following ways:
>
> a) As a duration delimited by a specific start and a specific end;
>
> **b) As a duration expressed in one or more specific components but not associated
>   with any specific start or end;**
>
> c) As a duration associated with a specific start;
>
> d) As a duration associated with a specific end.
>
> 5.5.2 Separators and designators
>
> A solidus [/] shall be used to separate the two components in each of 5.5.1 a), c) and d).
>
> **For 5.5.1 b), c) and d) the designator [P] shall precede, without spaces, the representation of the duration.**
>
> Other designators (and the hyphen when used to indicate omitted components) shall be used as shown in
>   5.5.4 and 5.5.5 below.

and later

> 5.5.3.1 Format with time-unit designators
>
> In
>   expressions of period of time or recurring time-interval duration can be represented by a data element of
>   variable length. The number of years shall be followed by the designator
>   [Y], the number of months by [M], the number of weeks by [W], and the number of days by [D]. The part
>   including time components shall be preceded by the designator [T]; the number of hours shall be followed
>   by [H], the number of minutes by [M] and the number of seconds by [S]. In the examples [n]
>   represents one or more digits, constituting a positive integer or zero.
>
> In complete representations the format shall be nYnMnDTnHnMnS or nW.
>
> For reduced precision, decimal or truncated representations of this format of duration the following rules
>   apply:
>
> a) If necessary for a particular application the lowest order components may be omitted to represent
>   duration with reduced precision;
>
> **b) If necessary for a particular application the lowest order component may have a decimal fraction. The
>   decimal fraction shall be divided from the integer part by the decimal sign specified in ISO 31-0: i.e. the
>   comma [,] or full stop [.]. Of these, the comma is the preferred sign. If the magnitude of the number is less
>   than unity, the decimal sign shall be preceded by a zero (see ISO 31-0);**
>
> c) If the number of years, months, days, hours, minutes or seconds in any of these expressions equals
>   zero, the number and the corresponding designator may be absent; however, at least one number and its
>   designator shall be present. Note that the removal of leading non-zero components is not allowed;
>
> d) The designator T shall be absent if all of the time components are absent.

All this is coherent with the wikipedia article, so the ISO-8601 of a duration of 500 ms should be `PT0,5S` or `PT0.5S`

Comment: Though ISO8601 allows fractions in the lowest order component, Java only allows fractions in seconds.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it just "PT0.5S" ?

Yes, it is a correct representation.

### Test using Java-8 standard library

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**Demo:**

```java
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Duration.ofMillis(500));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```text
PT0.5S
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

`PT0.5S` is correct provided the **ISO 8601** Duration format is
`P(n)Y(n)M(n)DT(n)H(n)M(n)S` there is no place for milliseconds.

So for `10 milliseconds` it will be `PT0.01S` and 1 millisecond can be denoted as `PT0.001S`

---

### ISO 8601

Durations are expressed using the following format, where `(n)` is replaced by the value for each of the date and time elements that follow the (n):

### P`(n)`Y`(n)`M`(n)`DT`(n)`H`(n)`M`(n)`S

Here

- **P** is the duration designator (referred to as "period"), and is always placed at the beginning of the duration.
- **Y** is the year designator that follows the value for the number of years.
- **M** is the month designator that follows the value for the number of months.
- **W** is the week designator that follows the value for the number of weeks.
- **D** is the day designator that follows the value for the number of days.
- **T** is the time designator that precedes the time components.
- **H** is the hour designator that follows the value for the number of hours.
- **M** is the minute designator that follows the value for the number of minutes.
- **S** is the second designator that follows the value for the number of seconds.

---

#### Example

To represent `9 years 8 month 7 days 6 hours 5 min & 4 second` will be written as

```
P9Y8M7DT6H5M4S
```

It can also be written individually as the 0 is omitted:

`P9Y` = 9 years

`P8M` = 8 months

`P7D` = 7 days

`PT6H` = 6 hour

`PT5M` = 5 minutes

`PT4S` = 4 second

See the use of `T` between `P8M` & `PT5M` to represent Month or Minute.

To represent 0(Zero) second you can use `PT0S` but to represent value in between like millisecond you have to use `PT0.5S` which is half second or 500 millisecond. The same will be true to `P0.5Y` to represent half year or `P6M`

Answer (score 0):

As of today, as an **unofficial** response quoting unofficial source, one may visit [timestamp-converter.com](https://www.timestamp-converter.com/) to find out the following example (loaded at page creation I guess)

```
...
ISO 8601
2023-08-25T08:35:16.792Z
supporting format: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z or 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
...
```